# Fluxcd sign its commits

Tags: flux, gpg-signature, fluxcd

I want to config Flux to sign its commit on the repository. I passed `gpg` key in `bootstrap` command but it just signs the first commit that it does for creating `flux-system` directory, but for example when I have a new tag in my image repository, Flux will change the image tag in my manifest in my repo and commit it and then apply in my Kubernetes cluster, now I want to sign this kind of commits as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following part in `ImageUpdateAutomation` manifest:

```
      signingKey:
        secretRef:
          name: flux-key
```

Image update controller will sign the commits.